# Cannot install ADT plugin because Eclipse cannot connect to Internet.

Tags: eclipse, plugins, repository, connect

I cannot install the ADT plugin on 64-bit Eclipse on Windows because Eclipse cannot connect to the internet. Consequently, I always get the error `Unable to find Repository`.

I checked to confirm that it is indeed Eclipse which cannot connect to the internet since the internal web browser cannot seem to connect to any sites.

Also, attempting to go to a site using external browser works fine.

Any ideas about how should I get eclipse to connect to the internet OR a workaround to install the ADT plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to proxy settings.

### Do you have a proxy ?

Do you have to go through a proxy to get access to the internet ?

Try doing this : `Start -> Run -> inetcpl.cpl -> Connections -> LAN Settings`

You should get something like this :

[image: Native Active Provider]

Do you have something there ?

#### System Proxy Settings - The easy way

Normally, if you have setup the system proxy settings there (`inetcpl.cpl`), those should automatically be picked up by Eclipse and should be categorized as ***Native*** under `General -> Network Connections -> Active Provider` :

[image: Native Active Provider]

Then *native* settings are those that are checked and can be distinguished as those with a slight yellowish background.

This would require that :
1. You check and setup the system proxy settings by configuring the same in `Start -> Run -> inetcpl.cpl` and then by going to `Connections -> LAN Settings` and then filling in the values for `Address` and `Port` like so :

[image]

2. Restart Eclipse. Then goto General -> Network Connections` and choose the Native Provider.

This method is most useful when you have complicated proxy settings with lot's of exclusions.

#### Manually setting proxy settings - The not-so-easy way

With this method, we'll setup the proxy settings only within eclipse like so :

1. Goto `General -> Network Connections` in eclipse preferences.
2. Choose `Manual` for the `Active Provider`. As soon as you do that, you'll see that the checked settings under `Proxy entries` changes like so : 
    [image: Manual Proxy Settings]
3. Finally, edit the individual proxy settings by clicking on `HTTP` for example, and then clicking on `Edit...` and filling in the values for your proxy server, like so :
    [image]

Using either of the above methods you should be able to get your eclipse connected to the internet.

Comment: I don't have any additional settings picked up in the Native provider. Do I have to manually add them? And if so how do I find the host and port number?

Comment: @StevenMcLellan  Please check my updated answer. I have added a section titled 'Do you have a proxy ?'.

Comment: My internet isn't using a proxy

Comment: Ok, so in the Proxy Settings for eclipse try choosing `Direct` for `Active Provider`. Does that work ?

Comment: Can't figure out what's wrong :(. Incorrect proxy settings are the only reason I can think of that this might be happening.

Comment: A shot in the dark by now. But try restarting Eclipse ?

Comment: What is the update site URL that you are using ? Try using `http` instead of `https` ? Check the Troubleshooting section here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting  . 

For the time being, you could try the offline installation of ADT as suggested in the troubleshooting section

Comment: I've tried both of those too. I'll just try the offline installation

Comment: If the offline installation works for you please up vote the corresponding comment so that it can help others in the future

Comment: I tried already but I don't have a high enough reputation... Sorry :/

Comment: @StevenMcLellan, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the 'Tick' mark next to it like so : i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png . There should be no reputation constraints for that.

Answer (score 1):

-add to your ini.
 Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient