# Eclipse update site freezes

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Aptana plugin with the update site. The problem is it freezes in "Calculating requirements and dependences.". 
I checked the error log in eclipse and there's nothing.

- Eclipse Java EE x64
- Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your proxy settings are correct. Take a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11849102/325742)** answer. I was thinking that the plugin installation may freeze if your eclipse cannot connect to the internet. If you open up Eclipse' internal browser can you browse to sites ?

Sometimes, the plugin installation has hung for me and I have been able to get by after **un-checking** the option to `Contact all update sites` like so:

[image]

Also, take a look at the Error Log and see whether you get any error there when Eclipse freezes. The Eclipse error log is located at `WORKSPACE_HOME/.metadata/.log`